# Edit an object based on an attribute's value in Django

Tags: django

I have a view called Edit, that edits an object. I want the user to only be able to edit it if it's unlocked, meaning, an attribute is called locked = BooleanField() and in the view, you first check whether the object is locked or not before proceeding.

This is the edit function so far:

```
@login_required
def editdossier(request, pk):
    dossier = get_object_or_404(Dossier, id=pk)

    form = AddDossierForm(request.POST or None, instance = dossier)
    context = {'form': form}

    if form.is_valid():
            dossier = form.save(commit= False)
            dossier.save()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'dossiers': Dossier.objects.all()

                }

            return render(request, 'dashboard/home.html', context)

    else:
            context= {'form': form}
            return render(request,'dashboard/modifier_dossier.html' , context)
```

And this is what I want to do:

```
@login_required
def editdossier(request, pk):
    dossier = get_object_or_404(Dossier, id=pk)

    # CHECK IF DOSSIER.LOCKED == FALSE:

    form = AddDossierForm(request.POST or None, instance = dossier)
    context = {'form': form}

    if form.is_valid():
            dossier = form.save(commit= False)
            dossier.save()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'dossiers': Dossier.objects.all()

                }

            return render(request, 'dashboard/home.html', context)

    else:
            context= {'form': form}
            return render(request,'dashboard/modifier_dossier.html' , context)
```

I did the following check:

```
if dossier.locked == false:
    proceed
```

but the condition is not checked. I tried `if dossier[0].locked == false` but it shows an error saying the object is not indexable.

Comment: Could you please post your `models.py` file as well?

Comment: The model is very long to include. Suppose the variable I want to access is this one: status_admin = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_ADMIN, default='ECV'). The choices are these: STATUS_ADMIN = (
        ('En cours de validation','ECV'),
        ('Validé','V'),
        ('Rejeté','R'),
        ('Prêt à clôturer','PAC'),
        ('Clôturé','C'),
    )

Comment: Definitely you shouldn't do `if dossier[0].locked` because it is not indexable. `if dossier.locked` should work as long as you've implemented `models.py` correctly.